# Several mocks of one module in one file with jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have to functions for example a, b. Both of them are elements of one module, and they are re-exported in index.js. `Function a` invokes `function b`.

It all works if i use `jest.mock` on the top of the file, but if i want to specify different mock implementation of b function in every `it` block it doesn't work. Also i try'ed to use `jest.doMock` but it doesn't work as well.

a.js

```
import * as fromDependencies from '.'
export function(arg) {
    return !fromDependencies && !arg;
}
```

b.js

```
export function b() {
    //some code 
    return boolean;
}
```

index.js

```
export * from 'a.js',
export * from 'b.js'
```

testFile

```
import a from '../a.js';

describe('isGroupOverlaidTest', () => {
    it('should return false', () => {
       jest.mock('../.', () => ({
           b: jest.fn(() => true);
       }))

        expect(a(true)).toBe(false);
    });

    it('should return true', function() {
        jest.mock('../.', () => ({
           b: jest.fn(() => false);
       }))

       expect(a(false)).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

The results are fake, anyway i want to call my mocked function not the original one. When i have jest.mock in the top of the file it works but i can achieve just one mock for on file. Do mock does't work. I'll be really grateful if somebody can provide some example how i can resolve that ;).

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#using-with-es-module-imports

Answer (score 0):

You could use a spy instead of a mock. Since `a` exports a function instead of an object then you'd have to wrap it.

```
import a from '../a.js'

const aWrapped = { a }

describe('isGroupOverlaidTest', () => {
    it('should return false', () => {
       const mockA = jest.fn()
       const spyedA jest.spyOn(aWrapped, a).mockReturnValue(mockA)

        expect(spyedA(true)).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

Something like that.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, it should be mocked b function from another module. Now i edited the post. But anyway if i try'ed this solution for b it doesn't work and still call's original function :(